# Check if two unordered lists are equal

Tags: python, list, comparison

I'm looking for an easy (and quick) way to determine if two **unordered** lists contain the same elements:

For example:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'two', 'three'] :  true
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'three', 'two'] :  true
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'two', 'three', 'three'] :  false
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'] :  false
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one', 'two', 'four'] :  false
['one', 'two', 'three'] == ['one'] :  false
```

I'm hoping to do this without using a map.

Comment: (Doing this in o(n) space without modifying inputs looks a challenge.) Add `['one', 'one', 'two'] == ['one', 'two', 'two']` to the examples.

Answer (score 614, accepted):

Python has a built-in datatype for an unordered collection of (hashable) things, called a `set`. If you convert both lists to sets, the comparison will be unordered.

```
set(x) == set(y)
```

[Documentation on `set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)

---

EDIT: @mdwhatcott points out that you want to check for duplicates. `set` ignores these, so you need a similar data structure that also keeps track of the number of items in each list. This is called a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset); the best approximation in the standard library is a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> import collections
>>> compare = lambda x, y: collections.Counter(x) == collections.Counter(y)
>>> 
>>> compare([1,2,3], [1,2,3,3])
False
>>> compare([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
True
>>> compare([1,2,3,3], [1,2,2,3])
False
>>>
```

Comment: CAUTION: Because using set() removes duplicates this solution returns True instead of False for the third example provided.

Comment: this is the best answer if you don't care about duplicates. Suhail's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19244156/403423 is the best if you want to check that they have the *identical* elements.

Comment: If you end up here because you have two sets that appear identical but are not evaluating as equal (as I did), check the `__hash__` function of those objects to verify that equal objects have equal hashes. Mine did not.

Comment: This is not a correct answer, and should not be accepted. sorted(x) == sorted(y) should be the right answer.

Answer (score 84):

If elements are always nearly sorted as in your example then builtin `.sort()` ([timsort](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/listsort.txt)) should be fast:

```
>>> a = [1,1,2]
>>> b = [1,2,2]
>>> a.sort()
>>> b.sort()
>>> a == b
False
```

If you don't want to sort inplace you could use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted).

In practice it might always be faster then `collections.Counter()` (despite asymptotically `O(n)` time being better then `O(n*log(n))` for `.sort()`). Measure it; If it is important.

Comment: `sorted(a) == sorted(b)` is my I think the cleanest approach here.  I think this answer ought to be the accepted one.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct because calling `sort()` on a list may change the sequence of its items, it is unacceptable if we do a comparison of two list and they become different afterwards.

Comment: @Reorx: Why the downvote? Have you read: *"If you don't want to sort inplace you could use sorted()."* in the answer?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Sorry for ignoring that words, but I think a good answer should be explicit and directly tell the reader what is the best way to solve problem, not just provide a controversial way with a dispensable explanation under it. I will withdraw the downvote if you can enhance your answer and tell clearly what's the difference of using `.sort()` and `sorted()`. Thank you :)

Comment: @Reorx: the best way if you can is to sort inplace: it avoids creating unnecessary copies. It is not always desirable therefore `sorted()` is mentioned. If you don't know what it does; click the link.

Comment: I think it's better to write `sorted` in the answer, for the beginner. `.sort()` is only useful for large containers to save memory. (It's not much faster than `sorted`.)

Answer (score 65):

```
sorted(x) == sorted(y)
```

Copying from here: [Check if two unordered lists are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/python-are-two-lists-equal/9623607#comment29031808_9623607)

I think this is the best answer for this question because

1. It is better than using counter as pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9623607/4279)
2. x.sort() sorts x, which is a side effect. sorted(x) returns a new list.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman They provided attribution, and they did not copy another answer, they converted a useful (+19) comment into an answer. That's valuable.

Comment: This is the true answer - and it can handle UNHASHABLE list elements. `set()` is sometimes not the answer (size, duplication...).

Comment: Well, still - it's worth reading Raymond's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829388/1338797 - some things, like `dict`s, are not sortable...

Comment: Thanks! this is the most simple yet effective solution. I have just a small set to compare, it is quite fast.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Short, exactly what the user asked for and without side effects.

Answer (score 21):

You want to see if they contain the same elements, but don't care about the order.

You can use a set:

```
>>> set(['one', 'two', 'three']) == set(['two', 'one', 'three'])
True
```

But the set object itself will only contain one instance of each unique value, and will not preserve order.

```
>>> set(['one', 'one', 'one']) == set(['one'])
True
```

So, if tracking duplicates/length is important, you probably want to also check the length:

```
def are_eq(a, b):
    return set(a) == set(b) and len(a) == len(b)
```

Comment: +1 Good point, I didn't notice that! On the other hand, it doesn't suffice just to check the length (otherwise `[1,1,2]==[1,2,2]`) -- you have to count up all the objects.

Comment: none of these solutions (even the last) will work if you want to check for *identical* elements (including duplicates)

Comment: downvote for `are_eq([1,2,2],[1,1,2]) == True`

Comment: downvote for `are_eq([1,2,2],[1,1,2]) == True`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you already know lists are of equal size, the following will guarantee True if and only if two vectors are exactly the same (including order)

```
functools.reduce(lambda b1,b2: b1 and b2, map(lambda e1,e2: e1==e2, listA, ListB), True)
```

Example:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> def compvecs(a,b):
...     return reduce(lambda b1,b2: b1 and b2, map(lambda e1,e2: e1==e2, a, b), True)
... 
>>> compvecs(a=[1,2,3,4], b=[1,2,4,3])
False
>>> compvecs(a=[1,2,3,4], b=[1,2,3,4])
True
>>> compvecs(a=[1,2,3,4], b=[1,2,4,3])
False
>>> compare_vectors(a=[1,2,3,4], b=[1,2,2,4])
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you do not want to use the collections library, you can always do something like this:
given that `a` and `b` are your lists, the following returns the number of matching elements (it considers the order).

```
sum([1 for i,j in zip(a,b) if i==j])
```

Therefore,

```
len(a)==len(b) and len(a)==sum([1 for i,j in zip(a,b) if i==j])
```

will be `True` if both lists are the same, contain the same elements and in the same order. `False` otherwise.

So, you can define the compare function like the first response above,but without the collections library.

```
compare = lambda a,b: len(a)==len(b) and len(a)==sum([1 for i,j in zip(a,b) if i==j])
```

and

```
>>> compare([1,2,3], [1,2,3,3])
False
>>> compare([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
True
>>> compare([1,2,3], [1,2,4])
False
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner answer to the above question is :-

let the two lists be list1 and list2,
and your requirement is to ensure whether two lists have the same elements, then as per me, following will be the best approach :-

```
if ((len(list1) == len(list2)) and
   (all(i in list2 for i in list1))):
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'False'
```

The above piece of code will work per your need i.e. whether all the elements of list1 are in list2 and vice-verse.

But if you want to just check whether all elements of list1 are present in list2 or not, then you need to use the below code piece only :-

```
if all(i in list2 for i in list1):
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'False'
```

The difference is, the later will print True, if list2 contains some extra elements along with all the elements of list1. In simple words, it will ensure that all the elements of list1 should be present in list2, regardless of whether list2 has some extra elements or not.

Comment: `def same(list1, list2):
  return ((len(list1) == len(list2)) and
   (all(i in list2 for i in list1))); same((1,1,2), (1,2,2))`

Comment: This is super slow, O(N^2) complexity

Answer (score 1):

What about getting the string representation of the lists and comparing them ?

```
>>> l1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> l2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> l3 = ['one', 'three', 'two']
>>> print str(l1) == str(l2)
True
>>> print str(l1) == str(l3)
False
```

Comment: it's two *unordered* lists.