# Check the sameness between two sets of `list type` or `set type` in Python

Tags: python, list, set

I have two sets of data with a list of list element.

For example:

```
set1 : [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [1,2]]
set2 : [[1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
```

I tried to use set of list or set of set for using set's == operator, but I have `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error.

```
x = set([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2]]) <-- Error raised
y = set([[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
x == y
```

How can I check if they are composed of the same elements?

Comment: What is element in your case? Is it a list or an integer? Should  duplicate elements be ignored?

Comment: related: [Python: Are Two Lists Equal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9623114/4279)

Comment: Let's simplify: are `[[1], [2]]` and `[[1,2]]` the same in your case?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you gave a complete example of the problem, as Python code that can be copied and pasted into a python session without editing.  For example, it's surprising you're seeing a `TypeError` when invoking the `==` operator: it's not even possible to construct a set of lists in the first place.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: It is *list* or *set*.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: They are different:[[1],[2]] and [[1,2]]

Comment: @prosseek I have added new answer,,, hopes will work out for your problem :) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's list is an unhashable type, you can make tuples of them:

```
>>> l1 = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [1,2]]
>>> l2 = [[1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
>>> set(map(tuple, l1)) 
set([(1, 2), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3)])
>>> set(map(tuple, l2))
set([(1, 2), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3)])

>>> set(map(tuple, l1)) == set(map(tuple, l2))
True
```

Comment: I think he's trying to flatten the list and make a set from that

Comment: or `sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)` if duplicates shouldn't be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is just to use a hashable type for the internal sets. `frozenset` fits the bill exactly.

```
> set1 = [[1,2,3], [4,3,2], [1,2]]
> set2 = [[1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
> def nested_set_equality(s1, s2):
      s1 = set(frozenset(e) for e in s1)
      s2 = set(frozenset(e) for e in s2)
      return s1 == s2
> nested_set_equality(set1, set2)
True
```

If order matters on the internal elements (like `[1,2,3]`) then `tuple` is the appropriate type instead of `frozenset`. If order matters and multiples matter (`[[1,2],[1,2]]`) we could make this even simpler:

```
> sorted(set1) == sorted(set2)
```

Comment: When order matters, I guess we have to use *frozenset* not *tuple*? I mean {set1 = [[1,2,3], [4,3,2], [1,2]]} and {set2 = [[2,1], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]]} returns true ([1,2] is reversed as in [2,1] for the second set) with your example.

Comment: @prosseek `frozenset([1,2,3]) == frozenset([2,1,3])`. It's not clear in your question what logical problem you're expressing. From your example, order clearly doesn't matter on the outer `set`, I'm asking if it matters for the inner sets or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to flatten the list and make a set from that.

```
set1 = set([el for sublist in lst1 for el in sublist])
set2 = set([el for sublist in lst2 for el in sublist])

set1 == set2
# True
```

You can also define a recursive function to flatten the list:

```
def flatten(lst):
    out = list()
    for el in lst:
        if hasattr(el,"__iter__"):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el

set(flatten(lst1)) == set(flatten(lst2))
```

This will handle any iterable of iterables n-levels deep.

Comment: Possible, but I don't think so. Note that the examples consist of equal lists in different orders.

Comment: @prosseek note that for your given example, flatten DOES work. I can't do anything but assume if your example is unclear :(

Answer (score 0):

```
#remove duplicate, arrange and convert to string. ie. [1,2] to '1,2'
def conv(l):
    d=list(set(l)) #remove duplicate
    d.sort()       #arrange
    return str(d)[1:-1] # convert to string ie. [1,2] to '1,2'


#now you can use that:ie
s1=[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2]
s2=[1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]
x = set([conv(i) for i in s1]) # <-- No Error raised.. :)
y = set([conv(i) for i in s2])
x == y
```