# Test if two lists of lists are equal

Tags: python, list

Say I have two lists of lists in Python,

```
l1 = [['a',1], ['b',2], ['c',3]]
l2 = [['b',2], ['c',3], ['a',1]]
```

What is the most elegant way to test they are equal in the sense that the elements of `l1` are simply some permutation of the elements in `l2`?

Note to do this for ordinary lists [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/python-are-two-lists-equal), however this uses `set` which does not work for lists of lists.

Comment: Are the inner lists considered "equal" if one is a permutation of another? In both cases, what about repetitions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
l1 = [['a',1], ['b',2], ['c',3]]
l2 = [['b',2], ['c',3], ['a',1]]
print sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)
```

Result:

```
True
```

Answer (score 3):

`Set` doesn't work for list of lists but it works for list of tuples. Sou you can `map` each sublist to tuple and use `set` as:

```
>>> l1 = [['a',1], ['b',2], ['c',3]]
>>> l2 = [['b',2], ['c',3], ['a',1]]
>>> print set(map(tuple,l1)) == set(map(tuple,l2))
True
```

Comment: This would lose information about the count: in other words, if `l1` had 10 `['a', 1]` sublists and `l2` only had 1, it would still say they're equal.  (Maybe that's what the OP wants, but it's not what I'd guessed based on "permutation".)

Comment: It might not be what OP wanted but this is what I actually needed searching with this question as in my case I did not have repetions and the lists inside weren't ordered.

Answer (score 1):

For one liner solution to the above question, refer to my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/python-are-two-lists-equal/28088925#28088925)

I am quoting the same answer over here. This will work regardless of whether your input is a simple list or a nested one.

> let the two lists be list1 and list2, and your requirement is to
>   ensure whether two lists have the same elements, then as per me,
>   following will be the best approach :-
>
> ```
> if ((len(list1) == len(list2)) and
>    (all(i in list2 for i in list1))):
>     print 'True'
> else:
>     print 'False'
> ```
>
> The above piece of code will work per your need i.e. whether all the
>   elements of list1 are in list2 and vice-verse. ***Elements in both the lists need not to be in the same order.***
>
> But if you want to just check whether all elements of list1 are
>   present in list2 or not, then you need to use the below code piece
>   only :-
>
> ```
> if all(i in list2 for i in list1):
>     print 'True'
> else:
>     print 'False'
> ```
>
> The difference is, the later will print True, if list2 contains some
>   extra elements along with all the elements of list1. In simple words,
>   it will ensure that all the elements of list1 should be present in
>   list2, regardless of whether list2 has some extra elements or not.

Comment: exactly what i have been looking for