# How do I compare two unordered lists of lists with unordered lists inside of them?

Tags: python, list, comparison

How do I compare two unordered lists of lists with unordered lists inside of them?

Assume that the lists within the two lists of lists are not necessarily in the same order. Also assume that the order of items in a given lists within the lists of lists are not necessarily in the same order. An example is shown below:

```
dummy_list_A =  [['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]
dummy_list_B =  [['B'], ['A'], ['D', 'C']]
```

I have already looked on Stack Overflow for answers to questions such as [Test if two lists of lists are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605834/test-if-two-lists-of-lists-are-equal) and none of them worked. You can see for yourself below that the most common answers to comparing lists of lists does not work for my scenario.

```
print sorted(dummy_list_A) == sorted(dummy_list_B)
False

print set(map(tuple,dummy_list_A)) == set(map(tuple,dummy_list_B))
False

print ((len(dummy_list_A) == len(dummy_list_B)) and (all(i in dummy_list_B for i in dummy_list_A)))
False
```

Comment: Should `[['A'], ['C'], ['B', 'D']]` compare equal with any of those?

Comment: Are the elements hashable? Building (frozen) sets may be more efficient than sorting.

Comment: @chepner That may not work as it won't factor in duplicated elements.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye No, [['A'], ['C'], ['B', 'D']] should not compare equal with any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply sort the elements in the sublists, sort the sublists and compare the two lists.

```
>>> dummy_list_A =  [['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]
>>> dummy_list_B =  [['B'], ['A'], ['D', 'C']]
>>> sorted(map(sorted, dummy_list_A))
[['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]
>>> sorted(map(sorted, dummy_list_B))
[['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]
>>> def signature(l):
...   return sorted(map(sorted, l))
... 
>>> signature(dummy_list_A) == signature(dummy_list_B)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to sort list elements of sub-list list and then main list

```
>>> sorted([sorted(i) for i in dummy_list_A])
[['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]

>>> sorted([sorted(i) for i in dummy_list_B])
[['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]

>>> sorted([sorted(i) for i in dummy_list_A]) == sorted([sorted(i) for i in dummy_list_B])
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dummy_list_A =  [['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]
dummy_list_B =  [['B'], ['A'], ['D', 'C']]
print( sorted(sum(dummy_list_A,[])) == sorted(sum(dummy_list_B,[])) )
```

> True

Comment: `[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]` would be considered equal with this method.

Comment: I don't think OP has specified if it should not be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort both the internal lists and the list of lists using Python's .sort() method.

```
  list_1 = [['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]
  list_2 = [['B'], ['A'], ['D', 'C']]

   def list_sorter(list_of_list):
       for a_list in list_of_list:
           a_list.sort()
       list_of_list.sort()
   list_sorter(list_1)
   list_sorter(list_2)
   print(list_1 == list_2)
   True
```

Comment: Please make sure you add some description about your answer. That's a good practice you can follow in SO.

Answer (score 0):

This how I would solve it.

```
sorted(dummy_list_B, key=lambda x: sorted(x)) == sorted(dummy_list_A, key=lambda x: sorted(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your lists of lists to sets of frozensets. You can then compare the two sets:

```
dummy_list_A =  [['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D']]
dummy_list_B =  [['B'], ['A'], ['D', 'C']]

set_A = {frozenset(i) for i in dummy_list_A}
set_B = {frozenset(i) for i in dummy_list_B}

set_A == set_B
```

> True

You can also perform other `set` operations:

```
dummy_list_C =  [['B'], ['A'], ['D', 'E']]
set_C = {frozenset(i) for i in dummy_list_C}

set_A == set_C
```

> False

```
set_A.intersection(set_C)
```

> {frozenset({'A'}), frozenset({'B'})}

```
set_A.difference(set_C)
```

> {frozenset({'D', 'C'})}

**NOTE:** If your outer list contains the same inner list multiple times, the duplicated lists will be reduced to one frozenset, so the following lists will also be considered equal:

```
dummy_list_A =  [['A'], ['A'], ['B'], ['C', 'D'], ['D', 'C']]
dummy_list_B =  [['B'], ['A'], ['D', 'C']]

set_A = {frozenset(i) for i in dummy_list_A}
set_B = {frozenset(i) for i in dummy_list_B}

set_A == set_B
```

> True