# Test if two lists are equal

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to write tests for my Django app and I need to check many times
if 2 lists have the same objects (i.e. that every object in A is also in B and vice versa).

I read on the assertLists/Sequence/Equal etc but for what I saw if the lists 
have the same objects but in a different order `(A = [a,b,c], B = [b,c,a])` then it returns an error, which I don't want it to be an error because they both have the same objects.

Is there a way to check this without looping the lists?

Comment: If the objects have a unique combination of attributes, you can sort them and use the functions you metioned.

Comment: Do you care about duplicates? If not you could turn your lists into sets and compare them. set(A) == set(B).

Comment: I have published a gist of my old code, where i was testing different methods of comparing two lists: https://gist.github.com/sobolevn/928cb960b1ce228a586d

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`assertCountEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual) in Python 3, or [`assertItemsEqual`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual) in Python 2.

From the Python 3 docs for `assertCountEqual`:

> Test that sequence first contains the same elements as second, regardless of their order. When they don’t, an error message listing the differences between the sequences will be generated.
>
> Duplicate elements are not ignored when comparing first and second. It verifies whether each element has the same count in both sequences. Equivalent to: `assertEqual(Counter(list(first)), Counter(list(second)))` but works with sequences of unhashable objects as well.

Comment: Useful answer but I am surprised this is from the Unit Test Framework. Isn't there some regular function in Python 2.7 which can handle this?

Answer (score 7):

If you are staying with list() datatype then the cleanest way if your lists are not too large would be :

```
sorted(list_1) == sorted(list_2)
```

Have a look at this Question (which is the same):
[Check if two unordered lists are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal)