# compare two vector Python

Tags: python, compare

If I have for example two vectors `a` and `b`,

```
a = [1, 3, 6]
b = [3, 1, 6]
```

since the content of the vectors is the same, is it possible in some way to compare them and get true as a result?

Comment: Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal)

Comment: I can not use 'sort' because in reality I have to compare only one piece of vectors.
my mistake because I have not explained my problem well, I wanted to avoid not to complicate the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```

Comment: thank you,
with this it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` and then compare. As pointed out by [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing), this is *O(n log n)* operation whereas the solution with `Counter` is *O(n)*. Since `n=3` in your case, the difference will be negligible but the difference will become apparent for large `n`. You might be interested in knowing this.

```
a = [1, 3, 6] 
b = [3, 1, 6]
sorted(a) == sorted(b)
# True
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal) you will find extensive discussion on this topic.

Comment: Note that `sorted` has an average time complexity of *O(n log n)*.

Comment: @blhsing: Hmm, right. May be the OP has small lists/vectors where it won't matter that much. But yes, for much larger lists, it might make a difference

Comment: @blhsing: What is the time complexity of `set`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 set(a) == set(b)
```

Because `set` automatically sort.

Comment: Your approach will compare `[1, 1, 3, 6]` and `[3, 1, 6]` as equal.

Comment: Right `set` contain only unique @timgeb.