# mismatched shapes error using "np.testing.assert_array_equal" on the same functions and inputs

Tags: python, numpy, comparison

I want to check if two functions get the same result. This similarity check couldn't be done by [list comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623114/check-if-two-unordered-lists-are-equal). The results contains both lists and NumPy arrays in nested form, so I tried to change them to ndarrays using loops and then try `np.testing.assert_array_equal`, but it get an unmatched shapes error:

> ValueError:
> error during assertion:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py", line 817, in assert_array_compare
> max_abs_error = max(error)
> File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in amax
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2755, in amax
> keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 86, in _wrapreduction
> return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (27,2,1) (26,2,1)
>
> Arrays are not equal
> x: array([array([[[0.21456296],
> [0.66358573]],
> ...
> y: array([array([[[0.21456296],
> [0.66358573]],
> ...

I don't know why this happened and if it is related to "*An exception is raised at shape mismatch or conflicting values.*" [in its documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_equal.html); Both the functions are the same with same data inputs.
This problem can be reproduced by the following codes:

```
import numpy as np

cv = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3], [5, 4]], dtype=np.int32)
vc = np.array([[0.73901752, 0.29121358], [0.43416323, 0.09588229], [0.66348142, 0.31610006],
               [0.82838408, 0.91985854], [0.80829238, 0.38857108], [0.95869708, 0.96481968],
               [0.02026681, 0.43935289], [0.95321295, 0.30348123], [0.7182516 , 0.85782094],
               [0.89697646, 0.99626489]])
change = 0.05
iters = np.arange(3, 8)
mi = np.array([[0.24122257, 0.56981744], [0.24122257, 0.14708398], [0.54651088, 0.14708398],
               [0.67472099, 0.20946646], [0.33991152, 0.36013738]])
ma = np.array([[0.66782044, 0.77456042], [0.54651088, 0.77456042], [0.69503927, 0.20946646],
               [0.69503927, 0.7711305 ], [0.67472099, 0.7711305 ]])


def ex(cv, vc, iters, change, mi, ma):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(85)
    Rand_ = []
    for i, j in enumerate(cv):
        rand_lim = []
        for m in range(iters[i]):
            rand_x = rng.uniform(mi[i, 0] - change, ma[i, 0] + change, 1)
            rand_y = rng.uniform(mi[i, 1] - change, ma[i, 1] + change, 1)
            rand_lim.append([rand_x, rand_y])
        Rand_.append(rand_lim)
    return Rand_


def new(cv, vc, iters, change, mi, ma):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(85)
    Rand_ = []
    for i, j in enumerate(cv):
        rand_lim = []
        for m in range(iters[i]):
            rand_x = rng.uniform(mi[i, 0] - change, ma[i, 0] + change, 1)
            rand_y = rng.uniform(mi[i, 1] - change, ma[i, 1] + change, 1)
            rand_lim.append([rand_x, rand_y])
        Rand_.append(rand_lim)
    return Rand_


ex_ = ex(cv, vc, iters, change, mi, ma)
new_ = new(cv, vc, iters, change, mi, ma)

ex_ = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in ex_])
new_ = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in new_])

# ex_ = np.array([np.array(xi, dtype=float) for xi in ex_], dtype=object)
# new_ = np.array([np.array(xi, dtype=float) for xi in new_], dtype=object)

np.testing.assert_array_equal(ex_, new_)
```

Why this error happened?

Comment: it's not an `AssertionError` but a `ValueError`, because `np.max` for [`error = np.abs(ex_ - new_); np.max(error)`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4adc87dff15a247e417d50f10cc4def8e1c17a03/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L817)  fails. I would say appropriate since your inputs are not *array_like*.

Comment: You can iterate both lists and assert the arrays after another.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, why `np.max` is failed? What do you mean by "**inputs are not array_like**", any recommendation? This can be done by two nested loops. I would be grateful if you explain more to cure without loops if it possible (may as an answer).

Comment: *ex_* shape is `(5,)`, which is a strong indicator that it's not a 2D array. `np.max` tries to reduce over axis=0 first, but fails because the inner arrays are not of equal shape. I think you can't avoid using a loop.