# Partitioning N-dimension array Creation

Tags: python, numpy

```
Write Function to Generate N-array with some decimal place 

>>> func(2,3) # 2d-array with 3 dp, sum those value to 1
[0.001],[0.999] 
... 
[0.999],[0.001]
>>> func(3,3)
[0.001],[0.001],[0.998]
....
[0.998],[0.001],[0.001]
```

I can create those array with when using nested of for loop.
When n> 4, creating such array is slow and hard.

Comment: You might do better creating constructor using `itertools`, since anything bigger than `n + d > 6` is going to risk memory problems regardless.

Comment: My target is similar to the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdBX-Hn2uYo&feature=youtu.be
How to split N coins to r people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `itertools` you could do something like this:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

def sum_generator(dim, dp, sum):
    i = np.linspace(0,1,10^dp)[1:-1].flat
    return it.ifilter(lambda x: np.sum(x)==sum, it.product(*(i,)*dim))
```

But it will still be very slow.  You're `ifilter`-ing a lot (essentially the same constructor as a `for` loop, but done in `c` so still much faster)

What you're doing is called [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) and there are some [efficient algorithms](http://jeromekelleher.net/tag/integer-partitions.html) for [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning) of such for integers, but they usually cover all n-dimensional spaces where `n < sum`.  You can possibly adapt one to your purposes but I'm not good enough at recursive logic to create an effective generator.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

I would try using a recursive function

```
def auxiliary_function(dim, dp, sum):
   if sum < 0:
        raise Exception("error")
   if dim == 1:
        return [sum]
   val = random.random(1, sum * 10 ** dp - 1) / 10 ** dp
   aux_list = auxiliary_function(dim - 1, dp, sum - val)
   aux_list.append(val)
   return aux_list
```

And then I will call `auxiliary_function(dim, dp, 1)`.

The goal of this auxiliary recursive function is to return a list of `dim` elements of precision `dp` whose sum is `sum`.

I let you adapt this function to return all the possible arrays you are looking for (mainly you have to replace the random generation of `val` by a loop between 0.001 (with the precision of `dp`) and `sum`.