# Efficient cartesian product excluding items

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I'm am trying to get all possible combinations of 11 values repeated 80 times but filter out cases where the sum is above 1. The code below achieves what I'm trying to do but takes days to run:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

unique_values = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)

lst = []
for p in itertools.product(unique_values , repeat=80):
    if sum(p)<=1:
        lst.append(p)
```

The solution above would work but needs way too much time. Also, in this case I would have to periodically save the 'lst' into the disk and free the memory in order to avoid any memory errors. The latter part is fine, but the code needs days (or maybe weeks) to complete.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Is `unique_values = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)` real or is that an example?

Comment: There are several implementations around stackoverflow of itertools.product in numpy, maybe that would be faster, otherwise, I'll try doing it in C or other fast language.  Also, why `np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)` instead of `range(12)`?

Comment: `np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)` is real. The example above is exactly what I'm trying to get. If I used `range(12)` I would not be able to check if the sum is below 1

Comment: @Stergios then you simply want the 42 partitions of 10, scaled down by a factor of 10: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partitions+of+10

Comment: @AlexHall I'm not exactly looking for the partitions of 10. For example, in my case the vector [0.1, 0, 0, 0....] is accepted (as long as the sum is <=1). They do not have to add to 1 necessarily.

Comment: My mistake, you also want the partitions of 9, 8, etc.

Comment: Moreover, [0.2, 0.2, 0, 0 ...] and [0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0 ...] are two different solutions.I need them both.

Comment: @Stergios that will increase the number of results substantially. The worst example is that there are 37,957,920 (4! * 80C4) different versions of [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0, 0, ...].

Comment: I know. That's why I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: What is this ultimately for? Is storing gigabytes of lists of mostly zeroes really your best option?

Comment: You can think of this as money. For instance, I could have 80 options to invest in and I want to see what proportion of my total money (1 in this case) should go to each investment. Based on these lists, I'm running some simulations on historical data, i.e. what would have happened if I had invested this proportion of money to each of the 80 options.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/45349125/2482744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this would be a bit more efficient, and you can use generator like this, and take your values as needed:

```
def get_solution(uniques, length, constraint):
    if length == 1:
        for u in uniques[uniques <= constraint + 1e-8]:
            yield u
    else:
        for u in uniques[uniques <= constraint + 1e-8]:
            for s in get_solution(uniques, length - 1, constraint - u):
                yield np.hstack((u, s))
```

```
g = get_solution(unique_values, 4, 1)
for _ in range(5):
    print(next(g))
```

prints

```
[0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0.  0.  0.  0.1]
[0.  0.  0.  0.2]
[0.  0.  0.  0.3]
[0.  0.  0.  0.4]
```

Comparing with your function:

```
def get_solution_product(uniques, length, constraint):
    return np.array([p for p in product(uniques, repeat=length) if np.sum(p) <= constraint + 1e-8])
```

```
%timeit np.vstack(list(get_solution(unique_values, 5, 1)))
346 ms ± 29.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit get_solution_product(unique_values, 5, 1)
2.94 s ± 256 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @Viachelsav your solution does not return all the values I need. For instance, it does not return the solutions [0.8  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0] or [0.8  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.0] which are valid. In fact, it returns exactly half of the possible solutions.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer. All I need to add is run the loop twice. Once for the `unique_values` and once for `unique_values[::-1]`.

Comment: @Stergios that's strange, because it actually produces all the correct answers. check `list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 0.8, get_solution(unique_values, 5, 1)))`

Answer (score 0):

OP simply needs the partitions of 10, but here's some general code I wrote in the meantime.

```
def find_combinations(values, max_total, repeat):
    if not (repeat and max_total > 0):
        yield ()
        return
    for v in values:
        if v <= max_total:
            for sub_comb in find_combinations(values, max_total - v, repeat - 1):
                yield (v,) + sub_comb


def main():
    all_combinations = find_combinations(range(1, 11), 10, 80)
    unique_combinations = {
        tuple(sorted(t))
        for t in all_combinations
    }
    for comb in sorted(unique_combinations):
        print(comb)

main()
```

Comment: I'm not exactly looking for the partitions of 10. For example, in my case the vector [0.1, 0, 0, 0....] is accepted (as long as the sum is <=1). They do not have to add to 1 necessarily.  Moreover, [0.2, 0.2, 0, 0 ...] and [0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0 ...] are two different solutions.I need them both.

Comment: @Stergios I understand, I haven't come back to this because that problem is a lot harder to make tractable.

Comment: It's  Ok. I've just added my previous comment under your solution for others' reference.