# Recursion for Integer Partitioning using numbers only once in Python is slow

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, recursion

I am trying to calculate the number of possible combinations to add up to a single value using every number just once in Python 2.7.

For example for 7 this would be 6+1, 5+2, 4+3, 4+2+1 --> 4 possible combinations

I managed to forge this into a recursive function that does the math right

```
import time

counter_list = []

def start(n):
    tic=time.time()
    recursive_step(range(1, n), n)
    toc=time.time()
    print(toc - tic)
    return len(counter_list)

def recursive_step(numbers, target, summe=0):

    if summe == target:
        counter_list.append(1)
    if summe >= target:
        return

    for i in xrange(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        recursive_step(remaining, target, summe + n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(start(7))
```

Unfortunally it becomes very slow when the numbers become bigger. Following are some numbers I meassured on my machine.

```
~~~ 40 ~~~
time in seconds:        0.0789999961853
possible combinations:  1112
~~~ 50 ~~~
time in seconds:        0.40299987793
possible combinations:  3657
~~~ 60 ~~~
time in seconds:        1.51200008392
possible combinations:  10879
~~~ 70 ~~~
time in seconds:        5.41400003433
possible combinations:  29926
~~~ 80 ~~~
time in seconds:        18.388999939
possible combinations:  77311
~~~ 90 ~~~
time in seconds:        54.5920000076
possible combinations:  189585
```

I have looked into dynamic programming principles. But I could not get it to work on that Problem. 
Any advice on how I can improve that script would be greatly appreciated

Comment: These are not the only possible ways to build `7`---> `6,1-->3,3,1-->1,2,3,1... 5,2-->3,2,2-->1,2,2,2...
4,3-->2,2,3-->1,1,2,2...` there many ways not just 4. Tell exactly how to get only those 4 combinations

Comment: This is a difficult problem, so don't feel bad about it being slow. Here is what an efficient solution looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209393/2482744

Comment: Note to commenters: this is "distinct partitions" rather than "partitions". That's partition function Q rather than P.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reference on this sequence: http://oeis.org/A000009

You can think of the problem of partitioning `n` into distinct parts as a coin change problem with (single) coins of values 1 to n. (Or one less than this, since it seems you're disallowing the partition of `n` as the single number `n`).

You can count solutions by adapting a standard coin-change dynamic programming solution.

```
def Q(n):
    A = [1] + [0] * n
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(n, i-1, -1):
            A[j] += A[j-i]
    return A[n] - 1

print(Q(500))
```

You can understand this program by noting that after `k` iterations of the outer loop, `A[i]` contains the number of ways of partitioning `i` with the distinct elements from `1..k`. And that the number of ways of partitioning `i` with distinct elements from `1..k+1` is the number of ways of partitioning `i` with distinct elements from `1..k` plus the number of ways of partitioning `i-k-1` with elements from `1..k`.

This runs in O(n^2) time, but it's fast for small cases (eg: partitions of 500 here, takes 0.033s on my machine).

Comment: This works! And it is literally so fast I cant even meassure how much faster it is then my solution! Seems like magic. I will have to spend some time trying to understand why it is such a gigantic difference. Thank you very much for your solution and your great explanation.