# Using recursion, I'm getting an answer one less than the correct answer

Tags: python, recursion

The question is:

> Given an integer array with all positive numbers and no duplicates, find the number of possible combinations that add up to a positive integer target.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> nums = [1, 2, 3]
> target = 4
> ```
>
> The possible combination ways are:
>
> ```
> (1, 1, 1, 1)
> (1, 1, 2)
> (1, 2, 1)
> (1, 3)
> (2, 1, 1)
> (2, 2)
> (3, 1)
> ```
>
> Note that different sequences are counted as different combinations.
>
> Therefore the output is 7.

```
def combinationSum4(nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    if target == 0:
        return 1
    elif target < 0:
        return 0
    elif len(nums) == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return combinationSum4(nums[1:], target-nums[0]) + combinationSum4(nums[1:], target)
```

The output is 7 but I'm getting 6 instead.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning and this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29

Comment: Why should the result for `target == 0`  and `len(nums) == 0` be 1 and not 0?

Comment: because an empty array consider being one of the solutions.

Comment: So if `nums = []` and `target = 5` the result is 1?

Comment: Umm. I'm not sure the question did not specify.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to introduce another approach to solve it by recursion, take a look at this:

```
m_nums = [1, 2, 3]
m_target = 4

def recursive_implementation(nums, target, cnt):
    if target == 0:
        return cnt+1
    else:
        for item in nums:
            if item<=target:
                cnt = recursive_implementation(nums, target-item, cnt)
    return cnt
                    

a = recursive_implementation(m_nums, m_target, 0)
print(a)
```

output:

```
7
```

for sanity check, I tried it also on the input - `1, 2` target: `4`
options are:

```
(1,1,1,1)
(1,1,2)
(1,2,1)
(2,1,1)
(2,2)
# output of the recursion - 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @YossiLevi's general approach, but I would avoid his extra argument and simply do:

```
def combinationSum(numbers, target):
    if target == 0:
        return 1  # base case

    count = 0

    for number in numbers:
        if number <= target:
            count += combinationSum(numbers, target - number)

    return count

print(combinationSum([1, 2, 3], 4))
```