# Find all partitions of n of length less-than-or-equal to L

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

How might I find all the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of `n` that have length less-than-or-equal-to `L`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209393/3614134), we can include an additional argument `L` (which defaults to `n`).

We might naively include `if len((i,) + p) <= L:` before `yield (i,) + p`. However, since `len((i,) + p) = 1 + len(p)`, any partitions of `n-i` that are longer than `L-1` are discarded. Thus time is wasted by finding them. Instead, we should include `L=L-1` as an argument when finding partitions of `n-1`. We then need to deal with the `L=0` case properly, by not running the main body:

```
def partitions(n, L=None, I=1):
    if L is None:
        L = n
    
    if L:
        yield (n,)
        for i in range(I, n//2 + 1):
            for p in partitions(n-i, L-1, i):
                yield (i,) + p
```

Now if `L=1`, the `for i` loop will be executed, but none of the `for p` loops will since the `partitions` calls won't yield anything; we need not execute the `for i` loop at all in this case, which can save a lot of time:

```
def partitions(n, L=None, I=1):
    if L is None:
        L = n
    
    if L == 1:
        yield (n,)
    elif L > 1:
        yield (n,)
        for i in range(I, n//2 + 1):
            for p in partitions(n-i, L-1, i):
                yield (i,) + p
```