# Find all unordered partitions of a list with a minimum number of elements

Tags: python, conditional-statements, partitioning, partition, minimum-size

A list of elements is given. I want to have all the possibilities to divide this list into any number of partitions so that each partition has at least x elements. The order of the partitions in the list and the order of the elements in the partition do not matter.
E.g.:
List = [1,2,3,4]   get_partitions(list,2) should return:

```
[[1,2,3,4],
 [[1,2],[3,4]],
 [[1,3],[2,4]],
 [[1,4],[2,3]]]
```

List = [1,2,3,4]   get_partitions(list,1) should return:

```
[[1,2,3,4],
 [[1,2],[3,4]],
 [[1,3],[2,4]],
 [[1,4],[2,3]],
 [[1],[2],[3,4],
  ...]
```

I have started to implement this recursively in Python, but I create too many redundant cases. For runtime reasons, I would like to reduce these cases in advance and not delete them afterwards with frozensets, for example.

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
def get_partitions(liste,min,max=None):

    if max is None:
        # Default setting
        max = len(liste)
    if len(liste) == min :
        # Termination Criterium
        yield [liste]
    else:
        for r in range(np.min([len(liste),max]),min-1,-1):
            # max for avoiding cases like: [[1,2,3,4],[2,6]] and [[2,6],[1,2,3,4]]
            for perm in combinations(liste,r):
                rest = [i for i in liste if i not in perm]
                if len(rest) >= min:
                    for recurse in get_partitions(rest,min,r):
                        yield [list(perm)] + list(recurse)
                if len(rest) == 0:
                    # r == len(liste)
                    yield [list(perm)]
```

This leads to:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4]],
 [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
 [[1, 3], [2, 4]], 
 [[1, 4], [2, 3]],
 [[2, 3], [1, 4]],
 [[2, 4], [1, 3]],
 [[3, 4], [1, 2]]]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Trying to use @mozway 's answer and extending it to a recursive version lead me to:

```
def get_partitions(iterable, minl=2):
    s = set(iterable)

    for r in range(minl, len(s)//2+1):
        if len(s)//2 != r:
            for c in combinations(s, r):
                for recurse in get_partitions(list(s.difference(c)), minl):
                    yield [list(c),*recurse]
        else:
            for c in islice(combinations(s, r), comb(len(s),r)//2):
                for recurse in get_partitions(list(s.difference(c)), minl):
                    yield [list(c),*recurse]

    yield [list(s)]
```

For the example list = [1,2,3,4], x=1 it is reducing the number of possibilities from 47 (my initial try) to 19. Still, there are plenty of redundant cases.

```
[[[1], [2], [3], [4]], <----
 [[1], [2], [3, 4]],
 [[1], [2, 3, 4]],
 [[2], [1], [3], [4]], <----
 [[2], [1], [3, 4]],
 [[2], [1, 3, 4]],
 [[3], [1], [2], [4]], <----
 [[3], [1], [2, 4]],
 [[3], [1, 2, 4]],
 [[4], [1], [2], [3]], <----
 [[4], [1], [2, 3]],
 [[4], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[1, 2], [3], [4]],
 [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
 [[1, 3], [2], [4]],
 [[1, 3], [2, 4]],
 [[1, 4], [2], [3]],
 [[1, 4], [2, 3]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one long-ish solution. No rejection is used in generating partitions, so in that sense this may be somewhat efficient. Still, there are lots of things to optimize.

Example:

```
list(get_partitions(range(3), 1))
# [[[0, 1, 2]], [[0], [1, 2]], [[1], [0, 2]], [[2], [0, 1]], [[0], [1], [2]]]
```

---

Here is an outline of how this works:

- First, it is useful to define a helper `split` function that takes a list `lst` and an integer `n` and return all ways to split the list into two groups, one of size `n` and another of size `len(lst) - n`.
- Second, we need to solve an easier version of the problem: how to split a list `lst` into `n` groups each of size `k`. Of course, this is only possible when `len(lst) = n * k`. This is implemented in `get_partitions_same_size` function. The idea is to always include the first element of `lst` in the first group and recurse.
- Third, we need to find all *integer* partitions of `len(lst)`. I copied code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning) thread.
- Fourth, for each integer partition `p` of `len(lst)`, we need to find all ways to partition `lst` *according to* `p`.

  - For example, say `len(lst) == 7` and `p = 3 + 2 + 2`. In this case, we can choose any three elements for the first group, any remaining two for the second group, and there is no choice to be made for the final third group.
  - This can introduce redundancy as we can get two partitions that only differ in the order of the last two groups.
  - To deal with this issue, we can represent a partition by counting the number of groups of each size. In this example, `p` corresponds to `p_scheme = [(3, 1), (2, 2)]`. The function `get_partitions_helper` takes in a list `lst` and a "partition scheme" `p_scheme`, and returns all corresponding partitions without double-counting. This is where `get_partitions_same_size` from step two is used.
- Finally, everything comes together in `get_partitions`: we loop over integer partitions of `len(lst)` and return all possible list partitions corresponding to each possible integer partition.

This is a fun problem and comments on bugs and optimizations are very welcome.

---

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

# from this thread:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning
def partitions(n, I=1):
    yield (n,)
    for i in range(I, n//2 + 1):
        for p in partitions(n-i, i):
            yield (i,) + p


def split(lst, n):
  '''
  return all ways to split lst into two groups, 
  with n and len(lst) - n elements respectively
  '''
  assert len(lst) >= n
  # handle special case of len(lst) == 2 * n
  if len(lst) == 2 * n:
    for first, second in split(lst[1:], n-1):
      yield [lst[0], *first], second
  else:
    for comb in combinations(range(len(lst)), n):
      comb = set(comb)
      first = [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i in comb]
      second = [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i not in comb]
      yield first, second


def get_partitions_same_size(lst, n, k):
  # print(lst, n, k)
  'return all ways to partition lst into n parts each of size k up to order'
  if len(lst) != n * k:
    print(lst, n, k)
  assert len(lst) == n * k
  if n == 0 and len(lst) == 0:
    yield []
  # case when group size is one
  elif k == 1:
    yield [[x] for x in lst]
  # otherwise, without loss, the first element of lst goes into the first group
  else:
    for first, rest in split(lst[1:], k-1):
      for rec_call in get_partitions_same_size(rest, n-1, k):
        yield [[lst[0], *first], *rec_call]


def get_partitions_helper(lst, p_scheme):
  """
  return all ways to partition lst into groups according to a partition scheme p_scheme

  p_scheme describes an integer partition of len(lst)
  for example, if len(lst) == 5, then possible integer partitions are:
  [(5,), (1, 4), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 3)]
  for each, we count the number of groups of a given size
  the corresponding partition schemes are:
  [[(5, 1)],
  [(1, 1), (4, 1)],
  [(1, 2), (3, 1)],
  [(1, 3), (2, 1)],
  [(1, 5)],
  [(1, 1), (2, 2)],
  [(2, 1), (3, 1)]]
  """
  if not lst and not p_scheme:
    yield []
    return 
  assert len(lst) == sum(a * b for a, b in p_scheme)
  group_size, group_count = p_scheme[0]
  num_elts = group_size * group_count
  for first, second in split(lst, num_elts):
    for firsts in get_partitions_same_size(first, group_count, group_size):
      for seconds in get_partitions_helper(second, p_scheme[1:]):
        yield [*firsts, *seconds]


def get_partitions(lst, min_):
  """
  get all partitions of lst into groups s.t. each group has at least min_ elements
  up to order (of groups and elements within a group)
  """
  for partition in partitions(len(lst), min_):
    p_scheme = list(Counter(partition).items())
    yield from get_partitions_helper(lst, p_scheme)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a partial powerset with a complement.

You do not need to define a max, it is fixed once min is set.

Also, including the full set is a special case (technically a full set is the set + an empty set, so it violates the min condition)

To limit the number of combinations, just stop with you have the first half of the total length. If you have an even input and  are picking the half partition, only compute half of the combinations (using`itertools.islice`):

You could use:

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import comb

def get_partitions(iterable, minl=2):
    s = set(iterable)
    return [list(s)]+\
           [[list(c), list(s.difference(c))]
            for r in range(minl, len(s)//2+1)
            for c in ( combinations(s, r) if len(s)//2 != r else
             islice(combinations(s, r), comb(len(s),r)//2))
           ]

out = get_partitions([1,2,3,4])
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
 [[1, 3], [2, 4]],
 [[1, 4], [2, 3]]]
```

other example:

```
>>> get_partitions([1,2,3,4,5,6], 1)

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [[1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
 [[2], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
 [[3], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]],
 [[4], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]],
 [[5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]],
 [[6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
 [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]],
 [[1, 3], [2, 4, 5, 6]],
 [[1, 4], [2, 3, 5, 6]],
 [[1, 5], [2, 3, 4, 6]],
 [[1, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5]],
 [[2, 3], [1, 4, 5, 6]],
 [[2, 4], [1, 3, 5, 6]],
 [[2, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6]],
 [[2, 6], [1, 3, 4, 5]],
 [[3, 4], [1, 2, 5, 6]],
 [[3, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6]],
 [[3, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5]],
 [[4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6]],
 [[4, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5]],
 [[5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
 [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
 [[1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6]],
 [[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 6]],
 [[1, 2, 6], [3, 4, 5]],
 [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6]],
 [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]],
 [[1, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5]],
 [[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6]],
 [[1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5]],
 [[1, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4]]]
```

Comment: hello mozway, and thank you for your answer. 
Unfortunately, the answer does not quite fit the problem I was asking for. I wanted all possible solutions, this answer only allows to split the list into 2 partitions, i.e. partitions of your example like [[1],[2],[3,4,5,6]] for x = 1 should be included too.

Comment: @Ripleys you should make it clear in the question then ;) That said you can easily use my code and make it recursive. Once you have the first partition, split the second one again, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Unfortunately, I don't find it so easy to implement recursivity here avoiding a bunch of redundant cases.

Comment: @Ripleys let's take an example: `[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]` can be split into `[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 6]], [[1, 2], [3, 6], [4, 5]]]`, this is equivalent to keep `[1, 2]` and only split `[3, 4, 5, 6]` again. No duplicate to remove here ;)

Comment: Ive edited the question, with my most recent try based on your suggestions.