# all sums of int generator

Tags: python, generator

I need to build a generator - all_sums(num, bound).

The generator will return a string which describes a connection between small or equal numbers to **bound**, whose sum is **num**.

Each string will be returned only once.

For example -

```
res = all_sums(4, 3)
list(res)
 output - ['1 + 1 + 1 + 1' ,'1 + 1 + 2' ,'2 + 2' ,'1 + 3']
```

This is what I did until now -

```
def all_sums(num,bound):
    lst = []
    new = []
    for i in range(1,num):
        lst.append(i)
    return all_sums_helper(num,bound,lst,new)

def all_sums_helper(num,bound,lst,new):
    if num == 1:
        return new.append('1')
    if lst[0] + bound == num:
        yield str(lst[0])+ '+'+ str(bound)
    yield from (all_sums_helper(num,bound,lst[1:],new)
```

I dont know what I need to do next.

I would be happy for any help.

Comment: Why does it specifically need to be a generator?

Comment: Your problem is actually related to integer partitioning - you may find this question and its answers useful in modifying your generator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning

Comment: I am learning for a test and this is the question , it has to be generator.

Comment: `new` is serving no purpose here.  Not sure what you expected it to do.  And you probably want `range(1,num+1)`.  You can replace that first loop by `lst = list(range(1,num+1))`.