# How to find all partitions of k positive numbers that sum to n with all permutations

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, combinatorics, partition

For `k=4` and `n=6`, we have

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 3 = 6
1 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 6
```

which can be obtained from the [Triangle of partition numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_partition_numbers).

But for `1 + 1 + 1 + 3` we can have `3` more permutations (4 in total) as follows:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 3
1 + 1 + 3 + 1
1 + 3 + 1 + 1
3 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

and for `1 + 1 + 2 + 2` we can also have `5` more permutations (6 in total) as follows:

```
1 + 1 + 2 + 2
1 + 2 + 1 + 2
1 + 2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 1 + 1
```

which I think in general, `binomial(n, n - k)` for every possible partition.

How to find all these partitions in Python or in Julia?

In Julia, my attempt is the following, which is I think correct but not optimal since I am generating all permutations and then applying unique to remove the duplicate ones.

```
using Combinatorics
n, k = 6, 4
comb = []
for partition in partitions(n, k)
    permuted_partition = permutations(partition)
    unique_permuted_partition = unique(permuted_partition)
    append!(comb, unique_permuted_partition)
end
```

Comment: is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning?

Comment: The problem is not integer partitions. Integer partition is a way of writing n as a sum of positive integers. I want to partition n as a sum of _exactly_ k numbers and further find all permutations.

Comment: These are called integer compositions

Comment: Could you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Julia, the following answers the question but I think it is not optimal since I am generating all permutations and then applying unique to remove the duplicate ones.

```
using Combinatorics
n, k = 6, 4
comb = []
for partition in partitions(n, k)
    permuted_partition = permutations(partition)
    unique_permuted_partition = unique(permuted_partition)
    append!(comb, unique_permuted_partition)
end
```