# Time-complexity of checking if two set are equal in Python

Tags: python, time-complexity

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python), I wondered how much time (asymptotically speaking) does it takes to Python to evaluate expressions like

```
{1,2}=={2,1}
```

that is to say, to check if two instances of the [set class](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) are equal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Comparison between sets is implemented by the [function `set_richcompare` in `setobject.c`, line 1848](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2fa7c104f909/Objects/setobject.c#l1848). You'll see that equality is implemented as follows:

1. If the sets do not have the same size, return false.
2. If both sets have been hashed, and the hashes differ, return false.
3. Call [`set_issubset`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2fa7c104f909/Objects/setobject.c#l1800).

The subset test for two sets looks like this:

```
while (set_next(so, &pos, &entry)) {
    int rv = set_contains_entry((PySetObject *)other, entry);
    if (rv == -1)
        return NULL;
    if (!rv)
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
}
Py_RETURN_TRUE;
```

You'll see that it works by iterating over all the elements of the first set and then looking up each one in the other set. So (unless there are a lot of hash collisions) this is linear in the size of the first set.