# Best method to check whether the contents of two lists are same?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two lists. the contents may be different. I best method to check and return `True` if both list have same contents. For eg: `[3,4,5]` and `[4,3,5]` then must Return `True`

Here is what i tried.

```
>>> x=[3,4,5]
>>> y=[4,3,5]
>>> x==y
False
>>> x is y
False
>>> x in y
False
```

it doesn't worked,
but when i tried these with `sort()` it worked :

```
>>> x.sort()
>>> y.sort()
>>> x==y
True
```

is this is correct method? Any thing better than this??

Comment: hashing the values is one way of doing it

Comment: Could your lists contain any duplicates?

Comment: What is the content? `int` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have one of the better methods to determine if the content in both lists is identical.

If your condition is that the content must be the same, but the order is optional, then using `sort()` and comparing them is a perfectly good solution.

Or you could do a method that does not involve sorting both lists and then also comparing them. This assumes the lists contain `int`s. But something similar could be done for other data types.

Using [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) you do not need to sort them, and you can make sure they have the same number of each element.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [4,3,2,1]
>>> Counter(a) == Counter(b)
True
```

Comment: This seems indeed the best method and is `O(n)`, if the items are hashable. Next best is sorting for items that can be ordered bot not hashed, which is `O(n log(n))`. A final method is `O(n^2)` if items are not hashable and cannot be ordered. See the [winning answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7829388/2647279) of the duplicate reported above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `set` here: 
`set(x) == set(y)`

Comment: Incorrect if one list is `[1,2,3]` and the other is `[1,1,2,3]`