# Python `Counter` seems slower than `sorted` in comparison task - why?

Tags: python, timeit

In reference to this older [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python) @Raymond Hettinger gets presumeably correct results where `Counter` is 4x faster then `sorted` using timeit from the command line like so:

```
python3.6 -m timeit -s 'from collections import Counter' -s 'from random import shuffle' -s 't=list(range(100)) * 5' -s 'shuffle(t)' -s 'u=t[:]' -s 'shuffle(u)' 'Counter(t)==Counter(u)'
```

My results indicate that `sorted` is significantly faster then `Counter`! Am I using timeit incorrectly? Interpreting the results wrong? Is the setup data somehow producing different results?

```
import timeit, functools
from collections import Counter


def sorted_lists(l1,l2):
    return sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)


def counted_lists(l1,l2):
    return Counter(l1) == Counter(l2)


short1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,5]
short2 = [0,1,5,3,4,5,2]
long1 = list(range(0, 1000)) + [100, 10, 1000, 5]
long2 = list(range(0, 1000)) + [5, 10, 100, 1000]

number = 1000

# Long test
t = timeit.Timer(lambda: sorted_lists(long1, long2))
rl1 = t.timeit(number)
print("sorted long  :{}".format(rl1))

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: counted_lists(long1, long2))
rl2 = t.timeit(number)
print("counted long :{}".format(rl2)


# Short test
t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(sorted_lists, short1, short2))
rs1 = t.timeit(number)
print("sorted short :{}".format(rs1))

t = timeit.Timer(functools.partial(counted_lists, short1, short2))
rs2 = t.timeit(number)
print("counted short:{}".format(rs2)
```

The output is fairly consistent:

```
sorted long  :0.04470205499092117 # less time = fastest
counted long :0.1182843999704346

sorted short :0.0012896459666080773 # less time = fastest
counted short:0.009829471004195511
```

Both sets of tests were run in python 3.6.

Comment: Different machines using different version of software yield different results. That answer is from 2011, meaning you are almost definitely running a newer version of python than they were, maybe you're running python 3 vs their python 2.

Comment: We are both testing on python 3.6 as per the recent comments on @Raymond Hettinger's answer to the old question.   Also, times will vary based on hardware, but not to this extent, where a builtin function will be significantly faster then another on one machine and significantly slower on the other.

Comment: Your inputs are small. A factor of log(n) doesn't mean much at this scale; constant factors can easily dominate the performance comparison.

Comment: Also, your longer inputs are nearly sorted, and `sorted` knows how to take advantage of that. It has a lot less work to perform than if the inputs were shuffled.

Comment: @user2357112 Yup, that was it. Sorted is really good at sorting things that are almost sorted or less then 50 items long!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user2357112's comments above, if the input data is modified as follows:

```
short1 = list(range(10)) * 5
short2 = list(range(10)) * 5
long1 = list(range(100)) * 5
long2 = list(range(100)) * 5

shuffle(short1)
shuffle(short2)
shuffle(long1)
shuffle(long2)
```

results:

```
sorted long  :0.055621962004806846
counted long :0.04698559001553804

sorted short :0.008079404011368752
counted short:0.014304430980701
```

The results are approaching Raymonds's from the old question.

A few more tests revealed the following:

`sorted` seems to be faster at long nearly sorted lists or any list under 50 items

`Count` is significantly faster for totally randomized lists over 1000+ items long.

Comment: nice comparision. The result is not surprising though since `sorted` _sorts_ the list which it cannot do faster than in `O(n log n)` time, in fact no sort algorithm can as that's the theoretical [lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list). `Counter` on the other hand does not sort, it only counts which it can do by passing through the list once taking `O(n)` time. Hence for any _sufficiently large_ `n`, `Counter` by theory and as you show nicely in practice is expected to be faster for this particular task.