# How to check if contents of two lists is same in python?

Tags: python, django, list

I have 3 lists :

1. `list_1 = [1,2]`
2. `list_2 = [2,1]`
3. `list_3 = [1,2,3]`

> Note: numbers inside [] are the ids from Django Model

I want to test whether the contents (but not necessarily the order) of two lists are exactly the same. With reference to the 3 examples above:

Comparing **list_1** and **list_2**
should return ***True***,

but if I do validation between **list_2** and **list_3**, or between **list_1** and **list_3**,
then the result should be ***False***.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks :D

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to test if numbers in `list_1` are in `list_2`, why would you do validation between `list_2` and `list_3`? And why would that cause it to return `False`?

Comment: Convert the lists to `set`, then use `set.issubset()` to tell if one list contains another.

Comment: Using sets is slower. See link at the bottom. Also, I think OP doesn't want to compare for trivial subsets but equality, rending your answer possibly incorrect. Oh and possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7828867/5775722

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Barmar, I want to check if numbers inside one list are equal with another, then the values inside them must be same

Comment: Now I understand. What you want is `validate(list_1, list_2)` is true, but `validate(list_2, list_3)` is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret your question as return true if the contents (but not necessarily order) of the lists are identical, otherwise return false. This can be solved by sorting both lists, then using the == for comparison. sorted() returns a list of integers in ascending order. This means that if the lists' contents are the same, sorted() returns identical lists.

```
def validation(list_1,list_2):
    return sorted(list_1) == sorted(list_2)
```

This passes all of your test cases. I might have misunderstood your question, please clarify if that's the case.

Comment: Actually, using `Counter(list_1) == Counter(list_2)` would be better in terms of time complexity.

Comment: I got **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'**