# Difference between two list of unordered tuples

Tags: python

I have two lists with tuples as shown below

```
a=[("a","b","c"),("d","e","f"),("h","e","d")]
b=[("b","c","a"),("d","e","f")]
```

I want to get the difference between two lists efficiently considering that the order of the elements in the tuple do not matter. So `set(a) - set(b)` does not work, which gives me `[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('h', 'e', 'd')]` as output.

Instead, I want the output given below. It should detect tuples as the same if the elements are just shuffled, such as `(a, b, c)` and `(b, a, c)`.

```
[('h', 'e', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets and come back to list:

```
>>> list(set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in a]) - set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in b]))
[('d', 'e', 'h')]
```

I order tuples to exclude tuples with same letters but in different order.

Answer (score 2):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python) gives you an idea of how to check for equality, *based on your definition*. Using this, you can loop through items in `a` to see if they match any in `b`.

```
from collections import Counter

diff = []
for x in a:
    if not any(Counter(x) == Counter(y) for y in b):
        diff.append(x)
```

---

An alternative is to sort your tuples then use set difference:

```
a = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in a]
b = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in b]

diff = set(a) - set(b)
```

Comment: I like your first one approach: `[ x for x in a if all(Counter(x) != Counter(y) for y in b)]` or closer to natural language `[ x for x in a if not any(Counter(x)==Counter(y) for y in b)]`

Comment: @daniherrera The "natural" one is a little easier to read actually. Can't decide if it's easier to read all smashed in a list comprehension though!

Comment: Ha Ha. You changed it! My comment was just a little suggestion. Anyway, I guess your `Counter` approach is better than the `sorted` solution I also used in my answer. By the way, `sorted(list(x))` is the same than `sorted(x)`

Comment: Oh you're right. I was thinking of the method `sort` which tuples don't have.