# How do I remove lists that contain duplicate values from a list of lists:

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to remove "duplicates" from this list:

```
[[4, 1], [1, 4], [0, 5], [5, 0]]
```

For example: `[4, 1] [1, 4]` are the same object, and I need to remove one of them.

How do I do that without using list comprehension tools?

Comment: You always have 2 elements in sublist?

Comment: Why "without using list comprehension tools"?

Comment: which one to retain in the case of a duplicate.?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar. Yes, always.

Comment: @SreeramTP Doesn't matter.

Comment: @ukemi because that's the requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently compare two unordered lists (not sets) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python)

Comment: A list comprehension is functionally equivalent to a for loop. Do you also not want to use for loops?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to sort it and append if not present in the final list like mentioned by LogicalBranch in the answers.

You mentioned you cant use `sort` and always there are `2` elements in the list. Then you can do a simple trick by making another list which is reverse of the list and comparing it in the final answer. See the codes below

```
ans = []
l = [[4, 1], [1, 4], [0, 5], [5, 0]]
for x in l:
    a = x[::-1]
    if x not in ans and a not in ans:
        ans.append(x)

print(ans) # [[4, 1], [0, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, you don't want to use `list comprehension`, `sort` and you always have 2 elements in sublist then following approach would help,

It iterates over the list and reverse the sublist and check if they present in the `new_list`

```
x = [[4, 1], [1, 4], [0, 5], [5, 0]]

new_list = []
for i in x:
    if i[::-1] not in new_list and i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 1], [0, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this (without importing anything) is by sorting each pair in the list before appending it to a new result list, like this:

```
result = []
for pair in [[4, 1], [1, 4], [0, 5], [5, 0]]:
  pair.sort()
  if pair not in result:
    result.append(pair)
print(result)
```

You could even convert this into a function:

```
def list_filter(collection):
  result = []
  for pair in collection:
    pair.sort()
    if pair not in result:
      result.append(pair)
  return result
```

Which you would then use like this:

```
list_filter([[4, 1], [1, 4], [0, 5], [5, 0]])
```

Which should return a list that looks like this:

```
[[1, 4], [0, 5]]
```

<s>You could make this even smaller using:</s>

```
list_filter = lambda collection: list(set([sorted(x) for x in collection]))
```

Which should return the same result.

**EDIT:** updated method without sort:

```
(result, collection) = ([], [[4, 1], [1, 4], [0, 5], [5, 0]])

def check(n1, n2):
  for pair in collection:
    if n1 in pair and n2 in pair and sorted(pair) in collection:
      return True
  return False

for pair in collection:
  pair.sort()
  if pair not in result:
    result.append(pair)

print(result)
```

You could even convert this into a function:

```
def new_filter_function(collection):
  result = []

  def check(n1, n2):
    for pair in collection:
      if n1 in pair and n2 in pair and ([n1, n2] in collection or [n2, n1] in collection):
        return True
    return False

  for pair in collection:
    if pair not in result:
      result.append(pair)

  return result
```

Which you would then use like this:

```
new_filter_function([[4, 1], [1, 4], [0, 5], [5, 0]])
```

Which should also return a list that looks like this:

```
[[1, 4], [0, 5]]
```

Good luck.

Comment: I am not allowed to use sort

Comment: Can you use a dict or collections.?

Comment: @SreeramTP No, I can use another list and somehow append the new "unique" sublists into there