# How to use list comprehension with in to compare 1D and a 2D list:

Tags: python

I have the lists:

```
a_list =[['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3']...]
b_list=['a','b','c']
```

To access an element that is letters in `a_list` we would do `a_list[0][0]`
However if I try to do this `a_list[0:3][0]` I kept getting the same result as `a_list[0][0]`. How might I get all three elements of the `a_list`.

This is problem because then I can't use the following code:

```
all(x in [['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3']] for x in ['a','b','c'])
```

The list I have is a lot larger so it would be nice if I can represent as a slice like this:

```
all(x in a_list[0:3][0] for x in ['a','b','c'])
```

But the list instead represents the index of the slice not the index of the list contained in the list.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: It should return true. Ohh I put d, let me edit that out.

Comment: Return true for what? all elements of b list are in list a, or all of first elements of a are in list b?

Comment: I want it to return true if all first 3 elements in the first index of list_a are in list_b

Answer (score 2):

Use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
import operator

all(x in map(operator.itemgetter(0), a_list[0:3]) for x in ['a','b','c'])
# True
```

Comment: Okay yes this works , I did not know there was all these operator functions! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per [How to efficiently compare two unordered lists (not sets) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python), you can use counter

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(i[0] for i in a_list[:3]) == Counter(b_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following? Iterate through the subset of `a_list` and test if sub-element 0 is part of `b_list`.

```
all(x[0] in b_list for x in a_list[0:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

checking the presence of each element of `b_list` in `a_list` 
and return `True` or `Fasle` depends on whether the element is present or not.

```
a_list =[['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3']]
b_list=['a','b','c','d']

a_list_1 = list(map(lambda x:x[0],a_list))

result = list(map(lambda a: a in a_list_1, b_list))

"""
output

[True, True, True, False]

"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
a_list =[['a','1'],['b','2'],['c','3']]
b_list=['a','b','c']

print(all(x[0] in b_list for x in a_list))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
True
```

Comment: what's different to my answer? :)

Comment: Ah, apart from the slicing, I did not see that beforehand.