# Python: How can 2 dictionaries with a list be compared neglecting the list items order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following are two dicts.

In case I have

```
dict1 = {'mylist' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
dict2 = {'mylist' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
assert dict1.items() <= dict2.items()   # PASS
```

and in case I have

```
dict1 = {'mylist' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
dict2 = {'mylist' : ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']}
assert dict1.items() <= dict2.items()   # FAIL
```

I needed to sort both lists to be sure the comparison will pass.

I don't care about the items order.

Note that I need to compare dictionaries which only part of the keys values are list and part of them are of other types.

Is there a more straight forward method to compare the dicts and comparison to pass even if the list items are being ordered differently?

Python 3.7

Thanks

Comment: Why not use dicts as values if you don't care about their ordering ? (note : you'd loose duplicates though)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to efficiently compare two unordered lists (not sets) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python)

Comment: @Bombarde I didn't understand you. Can you share an example please?