# How to compare two dictionaries with lists inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two dictionaries, for example:

```py
first = { 'test' :  [1, 2, 3] }
second = { 'test' :  [3, 2, 1] }

first == second  # False
```

Is there a way to compare these two dictionaries and ignore the order of the values in the lists inside?

I tried using `OrderedDict` but it didn't work:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

first = OrderedDict({ 'test' :  [1, 2, 3] })
second = OrderedDict({ 'test' :  [3, 2, 1] })

first == second  # False
```

Comment: `[1, 2, 3]` is not the same as `[3, 2, 1]`. If you don't care about the order, you should probably not use lists. OrderedDict is about ordering the keys, not values, which would make you problem even worse, since you don't care about the order of the keys either.

Comment: What would the equality criteria for the "list"? For example is [1, 2, 3] equals to [1, 2, 3, 3]?

Comment: Why *would* OrderedDict work? That just means the dictionary itself is ordered, it doesn't order the keys or values (`OrderedDict(test=[3, 2, 1]) == {"estt": [1, 2, 3]}` would be a very unexpected result).

Comment: I don't know what MongoDB supports, and I don't know what you are doing in general, but if you actually need a set, you should be using a set. If that can't go into MongoDB, you can convert when communicating with the data base.

Comment: you may have a look at [How to efficiently compare two unordered lists (not sets) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution:

```py
import unittest

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_count_two_dicts(self, d1, d2):
        self.assertCountEqual(d1, d2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first = { 'test' :  [1, 2, 3] }
    second = { 'test' :  [3, 2, 1] }
    
    t = TestClass()
    t.test_count_two_dicts(d1=first, d2=second)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter`s of your lists (or `set`s if you have `[1,2] == [2,1,2]`) for your contained lists:

```
from collections import Counter

first = { 'test' :  [1, 2, 3] }
second = { 'test' :  [3, 2, 1] }
third = { 'test' :  [3, 2, 1], "meh":"" }

def comp_dict(d1,d2):
    return d1.keys() == d2.keys() and all(Counter(d1[k]) == Counter(d2[k]) for k in d1)
    # or 
    # return d1.keys() == d2.keys() and all(set(d1[k]) == set(d2[k]) for k in d1)

print(comp_dict(first, second))
print(comp_dict(first, third))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare both dicts (True or False)

```py
first = { 'test' : [1, 2, 3] }

second = { 'test' : [3, 2, 1] }

is_equal = first == second

is_equal
```

Comment: This would not help me because it'll return `False` and I want the output to be `True` without considering the order of the inner lists.